# getRemainingTimeInMillis() AWS Lambda return negative value why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a handler to control a Lambda Function with 15 minutes timeout, which if it times out over 15 minutes, I call it again.

For this I am using getRemainingTimeInMillis() but in the first execution it returns a negative value, as following:

```
if (context) {

    // getRemainingTimeInMillis() that is returning negative value
    const contextRemainingTime = context.getRemainingTimeInMillis();
    const timeoutError = new Error('promise timed out');
    const lambdaTimeoutInMs = 900000;

    await timeoutHandler(
        syncInvoiceAccessesProductUpdate({ product, actor }),

        // Condition so that when there are 10 seconds left of the timeout, the lambda function must be executed again
        (contextRemainingTime > lambdaTimeoutInMs ? lambdaTimeoutInMs : contextRemainingTime) - 10000,

        timeoutError,
    ).catch(async (error) => {
        
        if (error !== timeoutError) {
            throw error;
        }

        new AppError({
            message: 'timetout handler test at sync invoice accesses product update job',
            payload: { contextRemainingTime, lambdaTimeoutInMs },
            code: ERROR_CODE.ACCESS_DENIED,
        });

        const agendaClient = await getAgendaClient();
        await agendaClient.now(JOB_NAME, {
            productId,
            actor,
        });
    });
}
```

[image: Printed result from log]

Why is it happening?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance of receiving a negative value from the `getRemainingTimeInMillis()` method as it always returns a positive number. Based on your code, it appears you are assigning a value to the `contextRemainingTime` variable and then performing some business logic. Instead of assigning a value to the variable, always read the remaining time from the `getRemainingTimeInMillis()` method so that you will obtain the exact remaining time of the lambda function.

---

To understand how the `getRemainingTimeInMillis()` method functions with the lambda function, simply log the value by accessing the remaining time directly from the context.

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
   console.log('Remaining time: ', context.getRemainingTimeInMillis())
}
```